# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) after using fread()

Tags: c, valgrind

For some reason, this super simple code gives me a valgrind error.
Code excerpt:

```
char* readFile(char* filename){
    FILE * f = fopen (filename, "rb");
    if (f){
        printf("sucessfully opened file\n");
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
        int length = ftell (f);
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        char* buffer = malloc (length*2);  <- line 109
        if (buffer){
            printf("in here");
            fread (buffer, 1, length, f);
        }
        fclose (f);
        buffer[length+1]='\0';
        printf("buffer: %s",buffer);         <- line 116
```

Valgrind:

```
==102== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==102== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==102== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==102== Command: ./run
==102==
==102== error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block
inputting file:
sucessfully opened file
==102== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==102==    at 0x483EF58: strlen (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==102==    by 0x48CEE94: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1688)
==102==    by 0x48B7EBE: printf (printf.c:33)
==102==    by 0x40172C: readFile (functions.c:116)
==102==    by 0x403108: main (functions.c:649)
==102==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==102==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==102==    by 0x4016BB: readFile (functions.c:109)
==102==    by 0x403108: main (functions.c:649)
==102==
```

Part of a larger program of mine is this function that reads a file and stores its contents in a buffer. This is the first thing the program does, so errors I have elswhere shouldn't really affect the behaviour here. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are using `buffer` even if it wasn't allocated/populated (in two last lines of your posted code)

Answer (score 0):

You have an off-by-one bug.  You read `length` bytes, into the elements `buffer[0]...buffer[length-1]` (zero based arrays, remember) and so the terminating null character should go in `buffer[length]`.  But instead you put it in `buffer[length+1]`, and so `printf` on line 116 is attempting to print the garbage character at `buffer[length]` that was never overwritten.

Another issue is that `fread` could fail, or read fewer than `length` bytes.  If that should happen, the remaining bytes of `buffer` are not overwritten, and then the `printf` will be trying to print uninitialized data.
You need to check the return value of `fread` to see how many bytes were successfully read, and respond accordingly if it is less than `length`.

Finally, if `malloc` should fail, it will set `buffer` to NULL.  Then `buffer[length+1] = '\0'` will dereference a null-related pointer, causing undefined behavior.  You need to alter your logic to properly handle `malloc` returning NULL, and not dereference or print `buffer` in that case.